# Find all possible segments with condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Input gps data:

| track_seg_point_id | time | elevation | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-08-25T05:06:21+00:00 | 388.0 | POINT(8.04428514093161 47.3935752455145) |
| 1 | 2022-08-25T05:06:22+00:00 | 387.79998779296875 | POINT(8.04427097551525 47.3935868963599) |
| 2 | 2022-08-25T05:06:23+00:00 | 387.39999389648438 | POINT(8.04424893110991 47.3936236090958) |
| 3 | 2022-08-25T05:06:24+00:00 | 387.20001220703125 | POINT(8.04422579705715 47.3936401214451) |
| 4 | 2022-08-25T05:06:25+00:00 | 387.0 | POINT(8.04420433938503 47.3936640098691) |
| 5 | 2022-08-25T05:06:26+00:00 | 386.60000610351562 | POINT(8.04417483508587 47.3936936818063) |

The goal is to find all 5-meter-long segments where the total elevation change is not bigger than 0.5m.
For example, starting from 0 till 2, distance 6+ m, but elevation > 0.5 m

```
with ins as (
select CAST(0 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(388.0 AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:21+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04428514093161, 47.3935752455145) AS geometry union all
select CAST(1 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(387.79998779296875  AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:22+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04427097551525, 47.3935868963599) AS geometry union all
select CAST(2 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(387.39999389648438  AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:23+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04424893110991, 47.3936236090958) AS geometry union all
select CAST(3 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(387.20001220703125 AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:24+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04422579705715, 47.3936401214451) AS geometry union all
select CAST(4 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(387.0 AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:25+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04420433938503, 47.3936640098691) AS geometry union all
select CAST(5 AS INT64) AS track_seg_point_id, CAST(386.60000610351562 AS FLOAT64) AS ele, CAST('2022-08-25T05:06:26+00:00' AS STRING) AS time, ST_GeogPoint(8.04417483508587, 47.3936936818063) AS geometry
),
t as (
select ST_DISTANCE(geometry, LAG(geometry) OVER (ORDER BY track_seg_point_id)) AS distance ,track_seg_point_id, abs(ele-lag(ele) over (order by track_seg_point_id)) diff, ele
from ins a
      order by track_seg_point_id
      )

select track_seg_point_id, 
sum(distance) over (order by track_seg_point_id) sum_distance, 
ele, 
sum(diff) over (order by track_seg_point_id)  sum_elevation
from t
```

then if I check the segment between 2 and 4, it is the needed one, cause of the distance 5+ m and elevation change is 0.39..

(to see it better I just added

```
where track_seg_point_id > 1
```

in t part
)

later between 3 and 4, it won't satisfy the condition cause of distance is too short and between 3 to 5 - cause the elevation change is too big, 4 and 5 - distance too short ...

In the end, there should be outcome like:

| seg_start | seg_end | distance | elevation_chng |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4 | 5.6393682810267158 | 0.399993896484375 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all pairs of (start, end) you need to, for each one of the data points, compute the distance between them and all the remaining data points.

For that, you can use a inner join, joining the data with itself, them, on the joining conditition, you set the rules that you're searching

i tried the following code and the output matched with your provided expectation

```
with

points_of_interest as (
select
  starts.track_seg_point_id as start_point,
  ends.track_seg_point_id as end_point,
  starts.ele as start_point_elevation,
  sum(abs(ends.ele)) over (partition by starts.track_seg_point_id order by ends.track_seg_point_id) as acc_end_point_elevation,
  st_distance(starts.geometry, ends.geometry) as distance
from
  ins as starts
  inner join ins as ends
  on 
    st_distance(starts.geometry, ends.geometry) > 5
where
  starts.track_seg_point_id < ends.track_seg_point_id
),

result as (
select
  start_point,
  end_point,
  distance,
  abs(start_point_elevation - acc_end_point_elevation) as elevation_change
from
  points_of_interest
where
  abs(start_point_elevation - acc_end_point_elevation) <= 0.5
)

select * from result
```

Comment: You are right about the distance, but there is still an issue with the total elevation change. Which is my main challenge. For better visibility: ele - 10, 8, 12, then the total elevation change will be = abs(12-8-10)=6 as it went down for 4 and then up for 2. And your example does work but only if the points climb up. As well, it is not possible to use just cumulative difference, like this: select abs(ele-lag(ele) over (order by track_seg_point_id)) diff cause when it counts diff between 2 and 4, 1-2 segment shouldn't be included.

Comment: I assume smth like 'ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT AND UNBOUNDED PRECEDING' should help here, but can't figure out how exactly

Comment: @KnowNothing i just updated my answer, can you check again pls?

Comment: yes, this one is what I was aiming for. Also, your first example gave me already a good idea. Thanks a lot!